# Bash - GIT small snippet for branch management

Tags: git, bash, ps1

Stupid Saturday morning code snippet.

I've found online a snippet code that allows me to get the current branch in PS1, wonderful! but...

I'd like to have different colors based on the branch.

I said, "You don't know anything about bash but should be really easy! just an if..."

After 6 hours of tests, here we go.

Could someone explain me where is the problem?

I know that there are many projects on GitHub that do this job for me, but I would like just to understand.

Thank you so much

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'

}

set_ps1_git_branch_color(){
    BRANCH=$(parse_git_branch)
    if [ $BRANCH == "(master)" ]; then
        echo -e "\W\[\033[35m\] $BRANCH \[\033[00m\]"
    fi
    if [ $BRANCH == "(test)" ]; then
        echo -e "\W\[\033[32m\] $BRANCH \[\033[00m\]"
    fi         
}
export PS1="\u@\h $(set_ps1_git_branch_color) $ "
```

It works just if I execute `source ~/.bash_profile` after each git operations ( like checkout ).

But the original snippet `parse_git_branch()` is able to change the branch name without the source command.

so...what I'm missing here? :(

Comment: only one equal symbol `=` is enough in bash for conditionals and is the right syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You have few errors:

```
 export PS1="\u@\h $(set_ps1_git_branch_color) $ "

 # should be (added \ before $(set...))
 # the \ will execute the command during runtime and not right now.
 # without the \ it will executed and determined of first run and not every time
 export PS1="\u@\h \$(set_ps1_git_branch_color) $ "
```

#### Colors format:

```
# Output colors
red='\033[0;31m';
green='\033[0;32m';
yellow='\033[0;33m';
default='\033[0;m';
```

#### Update script with the colors:

```
set_ps1_git_branch_color(){
    ...
    echo -e "${green} $BRANCH ${default}"
}
```

---

#### Fixed script to copy and paste

```
# Output colors
red='\033[0;31m';
green='\033[0;32m';
yellow='\033[0;33m';
default='\033[0;m';

parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'

}

set_ps1_git_branch_color(){
    BRANCH=$(parse_git_branch)
    if [ $BRANCH == "(master)" ]; then
        echo -e "${green} $BRANCH ${default}"
    fi
    if [ $BRANCH == "(test)" ]; then
        echo -e "${yellow} $BRANCH ${default}"
    fi
}

export PS1="\u@\h \$(set_ps1_git_branch_color) $ "
```

[image]

Comment: yeah definitely you have saved me from a big fight against shell script.
THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Yep. :-) glad to help.

Comment: the null dive in window is `/nul` instead of `/dev/null`,  so you may want to redirect the stderr to it with `2>  /nul` to make sure that the errors will not popup

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone is interested.

This script show the branch in PS1,
if the branch is 'master' the name will be red and blinking
if the branch is 'test' the name will be yellow and blinking.
For others branches, the colour will be white.

```
# Output colors
red='\033[31;5m';
white='\033[0;97m';
yellow='\033[33;5m';
default='\033[0;m';
blue='\033[0;34m';
magenta='\033[0;35m';
cyan='\033[0;36m';

parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

set_ps1_git_branch_color(){
    BRANCH=$(parse_git_branch)
    if [ -z $BRANCH ]; then
        return 0
    fi
    if [ $BRANCH = "(master)" ]; then
        echo -e "${red}${BRANCH}${default}"
        return 0
    fi
    if [ $BRANCH = "(test)" ]; then
        echo -e "${yellow}${BRANCH}${default}"
        return 0
    fi
    echo -e "${white}${BRANCH}${default}"
}

export PS1="${cyan}\h ${magenta}\u ${blue}\w\$(set_ps1_git_branch_color)${default} \n\\$ \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

Thank you so much CodeWizard! :)

Comment: Cool :-) glad to help up out. Feel free to vote on the original answer so people will know why its working for you now.